# Is functional componet more faster than class component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read in a few places to check this problem, but didnot find any good answer.
I hope good answer to it.

Answer (score 5):

There is not any noticable performance difference in functional and class components. It is completely dependant on developer's preference what one likes. Just the things to note is,

- you can `reduce the number of lines` in a functional component as compared to class component.
- There is also `fewer limitations` in functional components as compared to class components
- You can handle many lifecycle of the component just inside useEffect.

These all point in turn **reduce the time of development**.

---

You can refer to this article for more indept details: https://betterprogramming.pub/react-class-vs-functional-components-2327c7324bdd

There is also a benchmarking done in this article. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/136096/

Here are the findings:

[image]

You can notice here that, **functional components take less time than class components, but not much significant.**

Answer (score 0):

I think no.
It's unlikely to see any performance difference from classes vs functions.
However the way we optimize classes and functions are different.